# CoreML Model Compile Error compiling model trained in keras with Embedding layer as first layer

Tags: swift, xcode, machine-learning, keras, coreml

I've trained a simple model in keras and its first layer is an Embedding layer as below:

[image]

I converted the model to .mlmodel but when I try to compile the code in Xcode I get this error:

`/mlkitc: compiler error:  Inner product layer: dense_1: Product of input's C,H,W (32,1,1) must be equal to the input channels (16000)`

Could it be a problem with the conversion?

Comment: so have you solved it or no   I have a similar issue

Comment: I did not.. I ended up using a different model. But now Apple provides embedding, so maybe you can use NLEmbedding instead of using an embedding layer.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nlembedding